# How do you find the extinction coefficient for Gaia photometry?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astronomy, photometry

I have Gaia photometry g, bp, and rp. My final goal is to find the photometric temperature but first I need to account for reddening by finding the extinction coefficient. I’m really stumped on how to do this when all I have is the photometry.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The average value for extinction coefficient inside our galaxy would be about $1$ mag/kpc. If the object you have info on is in the Milky Way's disk, you can just multiply that times the distance the object is from us. If it is an external body (like orbiting in our halo), assuming the thickness of our disk is about $300$ pc and that we're at $z_o$ above or below the galaxy's plane, you'd first need to find the angle between the object and our galaxies plane, $\alpha$, and you'd find the portion of the distance included inside the disk is $(150-z_o)\text{pc }\text{cosec}\alpha$.

Comment: Finally, if the object is inside another galaxy or similar, you should take into account both galaxies' extinction. This is what I propose from what I've seen in exercises and been taught in class, though it is a bad approximation...

Comment: We also know that the coefficient in the visible spectrum is defined as $A_V=3.1E(B-V)=3.1[(B-V)-(B-V)_o]$, where $B-V$ is the difference of apparent magnitude in B and V filters and $(B-V)_o$ the difference of intrinsic apparent magnitudes (no reddening).